# 2 Week View FullCalendar not displaying correctly

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708621/jquery-fullcalendar-2-week-view-next-prev-buttons) and I am not sure if its because I am running a newer version of fullcalendar or what I did wrong.

[image: This is what i am seeing after i add the two week view.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

this line in the code `renderBasic(2, 2, weekends ? 7 : 5, true);`
should of been `renderBasic(2, 7, weekends ? 7 : 5, true)`
instead of a 2 as the second parameter it should be a 7 to show all 7 days in the week.