# Full Calendar - Load events by month

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, fullcalendar

Trying to make changes in a script to load events when user click on Next or Previous month.

Getting events from SharePoint Calendar using SPService library and need to pass a date to fetch events from respective month when user clickced.

Tried using full calendar viewRender but it doesn't works. Tired solution [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219381/jquery-fullcalendar-click-next-event-notificatin) but not able to kept track of which month clicked.

```
(function(){    
$(document).ready(function(){

    $context.find('#head-prev').on('click', function(){   
        $context.find('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
    });

    $context.find('#head-next').on('click', function(){            
        $context.find('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
        });

    // initialize the calendar
    displayCalendar();
});    

function displayCalendar() {
    initializeCalendar(false);
    calendarEvents = $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson({
                listName : 'NewCalendar',
                webURL : '/testcalendar',
                CAMLQuery :"<Query>" +
                            "<Where>" + 
                                "<DateRangesOverlap>" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                                    "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />" +
                                        "<Value Type='DateTime'>" +
                                            "<Month />" +
                                        "</Value>" +
                                "</DateRangesOverlap>" +
                            "</Where>" +                
                    "</Query>",
                CAMLQueryOptions : "<QueryOptions>" +
                        "<CalendarDate>" + formatDateToLocal(new Date().toISOString()) + "</CalendarDate>" +
                        "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>" +
                        "<RecurrenceOrderBy>TRUE</RecurrenceOrderBy>" +
                        "<ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'/>" +
                    "</QueryOptions>",
                mappingOverrides : {
                    "ows_fAllDayEvent" : {
                    "mappedName" : "fAllDayEvent",
                    "objectType" : "Boolean"
                    },        
                    "ows_fRecurrence" : {
                    "mappedName" : "fRecurrence",
                    "objectType" : "Boolean"
                    }
                }       
                });

        $.when(calendarEvents).done(function() {                           
                    addEventSource(this.data);

        });

}   
function addEventSource(eventData){

    var events = []; // holds our events
    var results = eventData;

    // loop through the returned event data
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
        var event = {};                 // new event object        

        event.title = results[i].Title; // get the title
        event.start = convertFromUTC(results[i][StartDate]);                     // get the start time converted to local time
        if(results[i].EndDate) event.end = convertFromUTC(results[i][EndDate]);  // if there's an end time, convert it to local
        event.color = categoriesMap.get(results[i][EventCategory]);
        events.push(event); // add the event to the array
    }

    // add the events to the calendar
    $context.find("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);        
}      
// renders a new calendar
function initializeCalendar(initialized){
    $context.find('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy'); // destroy any existing calendar

    // initialize the calendar with options
    $context.find('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //which buttons are in the header
        header: false,
        //set the button text for the today button
        buttonText: {
            today: "Today"
        },
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
        nowIndicator: true,                                     // agenda views include a bar indicating current time     
        droppable: false,                                       // prevent external events from being dropped in
        eventLimit: true,                                       // any events that don't fit will have a "+n" icon            
        viewRender: function(view) {

            var title = view.title;
            title = title.split(",");

            if(title.length == 1){
                title = title[0].split(" ");               
            }                


            $context.find('#head-month').text(title[0]);
            $context.find('#head-year').text(title[1]);                                                
        }
    }); // ==== End Calendar Initialization ====

    // go to the correct date from a previous view
    if(initialized){
        $context.find('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', view.intervalStart);
    }
}
```

});}());   // end IIFE

Comment: If you use this pattern to define your events: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function then fullCalendar will a) re-run your fetch function every time the user changes the date range or the view on the calendar and b) give you the start and end dates of the current range so you can tell your server what dates to fetch events for.